# Wordpress plugin admin settings page

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, settings, admin

I'm working on a very simple plugin for wordpress. I'm dealing with "admin settings page".

I'd like to keep things separated in php files, as most tutorials do, but something broke in my code when I have my admin registered sections and fields in a `required_once` template.php as I'm not able to call `add_action` from there.

Is there any way to keep the function of `register_setting` and its callback and all this stuff, in a different file from the main plugin one?

I'd like to get rid of the `config_apiplugin_init` function and all callbacks from this main file, so I can keep it organised.

And if I use the 3rd `add_action` in the secondary file (as most tutorials do) I doesn't work, I think because I use a class.

```
    <?php

defined ( 'ABSPATH' ) or die ( 'No pots accedir aqui!' );

class ApiPlugin {

function __construct(){
    $this->plugin = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
}    

function register() {
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue') );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_admin_pages' ) );
    
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'config_apiplugin_init' ) );

    add_filter( "plugin_action_links_$this->plugin", array( $this, 'settings_link' ) );
}

public function settings_link( $links ) {
    $settings_link = '<a href="admin.php?page=apiplugin_page"> Opcions </a>';
    array_push( $links, $settings_link );
    return $links;
}

public function add_admin_pages() {
    add_menu_page( 'Gestio de la API-IGD', 'API-IGD Config', 'manage_options', 'apiplugin_page', array( $this, 'admin_index_html' ), 'dashicons-admin-links', 110 );
}

function config_apiplugin_init() {

    add_settings_section( 
        'apiplugin_settings_section', 
        '', 
        array( $this, 'apiplugin_section_callback' ),
        'apiplugin_page' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'apiplugin_url', 
        __('URL del feed', 'ardstudio-api-igd'),
        array( $this, 'apiplugin_url_callback' ),
        'apiplugin_page', 
        'apiplugin_settings_section' 
    );

    register_setting( 
        'apiplugin_group', 
        'apiplugin_url', 
        array( 'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field', 'default' => '') 
    ); 

    add_settings_field( 
        'filtre_id', 
        __('Id d\'ubicació', 'ardstudio-api-igd'),
        array( $this, 'apiplugin_field_callback' ),
        'apiplugin_page', 
        'apiplugin_settings_section' 
    );
    
    register_setting( 
        'apiplugin_group', 
        'filtre_id', 
        array( 'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field', 'default' => '') 
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'mostra_a_pagina',
        __( 'A quina pàgina mostrem el feed', 'ardstudio-api-igd' ),
        array( $this,'mostra_a_pagina_callback' ),
        'apiplugin_page',
        'apiplugin_settings_section'
    );

    register_setting(
        'apiplugin_group',
        'mostra_a_pagina',
        array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
            'default' => ''
        )
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'plantilla',
        __( 'Mostra Nou model', 'ardstudio-api-igd' ),
        array( $this, 'plantilla_callback' ),
        'apiplugin_page',
        'apiplugin_settings_section'
    );
    
    register_setting(
        'apiplugin_group',
        'plantilla',
        array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
            'default' => ''
        )
    );

}
function apiplugin_section_callback() {
    echo 'Configura l\'opció per filtrar el feed segons l\'ubicació';
}

function apiplugin_field_callback(){
    $filtre_id = get_option('filtre_id');
    echo '<input type="text" name="filtre_id" class="regular-text" value="'.$filtre_id.'" />';
}

function apiplugin_url_callback(){
    $apiplugin_url = get_option('apiplugin_url');
    echo '<input type="text" name="apiplugin_url" class="regular-text" value="'.$apiplugin_url.'" />';
}

function mostra_a_pagina_callback(){
    $args = array(
        'echo'             => 1,
        'selected' => get_option( 'mostra_a_pagina' ),
        'name'  => 'mostra_a_pagina',
        'value' => '',
        'id' => ''
    );
    wp_dropdown_pages($args); 
}

function plantilla_callback(){
    $plantilla = get_option('plantilla');
    ?>
    <label for="value1">
        <input type="radio" name="plantilla" value="value1" <?php checked( 'value1', $plantilla ); ?>/> Nova Visualització
    </label>
    <label for="value2">
        <input type="radio" name="plantilla" value="value2" <?php checked( 'value2', $plantilla ); ?>/> Visualitza en una Taula
    </label>
    <?php
}

public function admin_index_html(){
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/admin.php';
    
}

function activate(){
    echo 'Activat correctament';
}

function deactivate(){
    echo 'Desactivat correctament';
}

function uninstall(){
    
}
    
function enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'apiIgdStyles', plugins_url( '/assets/styles.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_scripts( 'apiIgdScripts', plugins_url( '/assets/scripts.js', __FILE__ ) );
}
    
}
// require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/admin-test.php';

require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/functions.php';

if ( class_exists( 'ApiPlugin' )) {
    $apiIgd = new ApiPlugin();
    $apiIgd->register();
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your code so we can help you better

Comment: I edited my post, so it can be clearer. Thanks

Comment: You just miss to call it in the construct.

Comment: what should I call in the construct?